# AndroidThings UsbToUart cannot Rx data when run long times [close]

Tags: android, android-things

Hello I use android thing on raspberry pi 3, I have a problem my app use UsbToSerial and then my app can Tx but cannot Rx data when app run longtime but in first period of work my app can Rx data and app can Tx alway times

How can I fix the problem?
And this is my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        UartService uart_api = new UartService();
        uart_api.UartInit("USB1-1.2:1.0", 9600);
    }
```

**UartService.java**

```
public class UartService extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "LoopbackActivity";
    // UART Configuration Parameters
    private static final int DATA_BITS = 8;
    private static final int STOP_BITS = 1;
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 512;
    private UartDevice mLoopbackDevice;

    private void openUart(String name, int baudRate) throws IOException {
        mLoopbackDevice = PeripheralManager.getInstance().openUartDevice(name);
        // Configure the UART
        mLoopbackDevice.setBaudrate(baudRate);
        mLoopbackDevice.setDataSize(DATA_BITS);
        mLoopbackDevice.setParity(UartDevice.PARITY_NONE);
        mLoopbackDevice.setStopBits(STOP_BITS);
    }

    public void UartInit(String UartName, int baudrate){
        PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
        List<String> deviceList = manager.getUartDeviceList();
        if (deviceList.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "No UART port available on this device.");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "List of available devices: " + deviceList);
        }

        // Attempt to access the UART device
        try {
            openUart(UartName, baudrate);
            // Read any initially buffered data
            Thread thread_read = new Thread(new ThreadUart(123));
            thread_read.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to open UART device", e);
        }
    }

    public class ThreadUart implements Runnable {

        private int data_in;

        public ThreadUart(int in) {
            this.data_in = in;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                ///////// Test Rx //////
                if (mLoopbackDevice != null) {
                    // Loop until there is no more data in the RX buffer.
                    try {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
                        int read;
                        while ((read = mLoopbackDevice.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {   // <<<< when run long time this cannot Rx data
                            mLoopbackDevice.write(buffer, read);
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to transfer data over UART", e);
                    }
                }
                // sleep 1 sec.
                ///////// Test Tx //////
                String string = "Hello\r\n";
                byte[] b = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                try {
                    mLoopbackDevice.write(b, b.length); // <<<< can Tx work!! always time
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finarly I follow [Example](https://github.com/Nilhcem/usbfun-androidthings) example, It work !! in example use felHR85’s USBSerial library

however I don't know cause of Rx lost when use UART API and then run long time